# Creating auto increment PK via pgAdmin GUI Not Working

Tags: postgresql

I don't know what I'm missing here.  I simply want an auto incremented id here.  I thought setting PK to true would do that:

[image]

Then tried to run this query:

```
INSERT INTO public.social_type(name)
    VALUES ('personal blog');
```

**But got this error:**

```
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, personal blog).
SQL state: 23502
```

Answer (score 0):

the type `integer` does not mean it will generate a value. To do so, select the `serial` type instead

Comment: With modern Postgres versions [identity columns](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) are preferred over serial

Comment: what do you mean identity column, is that a type?  how can I specify that via the GUI?  How do I essentially do this but through the GUI, what options do the same thing as `column_name type GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY[`

Comment: and how can you make a column an Identity After the fact through the GUI not through scripts?

Comment: Right click on column name --> Properties --> Constraints--> Type. Select `IDENTITY`.  Change options as desired. Then go back up to table name -->Properties --> Columns and make the column `PRIMARY KEY`.